# python list comprehension function syntax error

Tags: python

I'm trying to do `python list comprehension`, but I get a syntax error.  I'm not familiar with `python list comprehension`, so I can't seem to understand why this is erroring out.

```
>>> s = set()
>>> def in_set(s, val):
        if val in s:
            return True
        else:
            s.add(val)
            return False

>>> [x for x in v0.outV() if x.eid not in_set(s, x.eid)]
  File "<input>", line 1
    [x for x in v0.outV() if x.eid not in_set(s, x.eid)]
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> print "This Works"
This Works
>>> in_set(s, v0.eid)
False
```

`v0.outV()` is a `generator`, `x` is an `object`, and `x.eid` is a `string`.

Comment: I think you mean `if not in_set(s, x.eid)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your code structure, I believe that you want this:

```
[x for x in v0.outV() if not in_set(s, x.eid)]
```

Here is a reference on [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).